# No relationship between husband and wife from three years

Tags: practical-islam, relationships, husband-wife

What if there is no relationship from consecutive 3 years between a husband and wife and they have intention to divorce each other but did not do this because of family pressure? What is the status of their so called marriage?

Comment: Didn't you just describe the status of their marriage?

Comment: I need to know about their marriage status with respect to Quran and Hadith. In the light of Islam

Comment: What do you want to know about their marriage?

Comment: @Daniel, I think OP wants to know if there is no relationship between husband and wife for x amount of years, does the marriage islamically become invalid automatically after a certain amount of time for being in a non relationship marriage? OP correct me if I am wrong..  Or is the marriage always islamically valid, no matter how long it's been without a relationship between husband and wife.

Comment: yes you are very much right

Answer (score -3):

You should pay attention that a common family pressure doesn’t seem to be considered as an Islamic license for preventing the divorce. Then you’d better to do it without paying attention to their pressure. Do it according to Islamic laws, then you’d be freer to choose another wife or husband, although you’d better attempt to reach an agreement to carrying on your life. Don’t forget that according to Islam, divorce has some conditions: ([www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa8230))

---

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa8230)

Comment: I request you to plz read the question carefully.